# como obtener el valor de un evento click y pasarlo dinamicamente a otra funcion en angular

Tags: javascript, angular

estoy aprendiendo angular. y se me ocurre hacer una calculadora.
la hice con dos inputs pero ahora la quiero hacer con botones,
se me ocurre que a cada botón ya sea 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 agregarle un evento click y por ejemplo en la funcion suma detectar en que dos botones se hizo el click para hacer la operacion. pero no se como detectar el click de una funcion a otra y pasarle el valor
si me pueden ayudar,gracias :)

codigo js

```
 export class CalculadoraComponent {
 numero01 = 0;
 numero02 = 2;
 numero03 = 3;
 resultado = 0


 //el valor de la variable debe ser del boton presionado 
 obtener1(){
 this.numero01 = 1
  }

 sumar(){

 this.resultado = this.numero01 + this.numero02
 }
 restar(){
 this.resultado = this.numero01 - this.numero02
 }
 multiplicar(){
 this.resultado = this.numero01 * this.numero02
 }
 dividir(){
 this.resultado = this.numero01 / this.numero02
 }


}
```

el html

```
    <button [(ngModel)]='numero01' (click)="obtener1()"  class="btn btn-primary" 
     value=1>1</button>
      {{numero01}}
      <button [(ngModel)]='numero02' class="btn btn-primary">2</button>
      <button [(ngModel)]='numero03' class="btn btn-primary">3</button>
      <br>
      
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="sumar()"><i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i> 
    </button>
           <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="restar()"><i class="bi bi-dash"></i> 
     </button>
           <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="multiplicar()"><i class="bi bi-x"> 
     </i></button>
           <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="dividir()"><i class="bi bi- 
      percent"></i></button>
        <p>El resultado es : {{resultado}}</p>
```

Comment: *detectar el click de una funcion a otra y pasarle el valor* -> a que te refieres con eso? cómo quieres que sea el resultado? no logro a entender bien, tu código está bien al parecer...

Comment: Que el resultado de la suma() sean los valores que se obtienen al hacer click, en el caso de que hubiera un tercer boton. Numero1 + numero2 o número1 + número3, etc